# Lightning Community navigation

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community

The child Aura component init handler does not load when urlRedirect is used. Is there a better way to navigate to another page within community other then following code block? If this is a legitimate way to perform navigation then how can I make sure that init handler is triggered and rest of the JS controller methods are loaded? At the moment rest of the JS methods are not loading.

```
    var urlRedirect = "/my-profile";
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({ "url": urlRedirect});
    urlEvent.fire();
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
```

Comment: Can you try with this one? https://www.infallibletechie.com/2020/02/navigating-to-page-in-lightning.html

Comment: that link was helpful, thanks for sharing. I also found some guidance in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_web_page.htm?search_text=navigate and https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm?search_text=navigate